# Removing a programatically created view iOS

Tags: ios, button, view

in my game app i created a view programatically with a uibutton.
 by clicking the button the whole view shall be removed. but i had no success with all my attempts to remove the view with "[polygonView removeFromSuperview];" for example. 
I think i need to 
get the current view first but have no idea how to do that and to implement that in the
button method.

here is the code:

```
- (void) addNewView {
    UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;

    UIView *polygonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake ( 60, 0, 900, 900)];
    polygonView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    polygonView.tag = 42;
    // [self playMovie];

    [window addSubview:polygonView];

    // [polygonView setHidden:NO];

    [polygonView release];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 170, 100, 30);

    [button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [polygonView addSubview:button];

    // NSLog(@"mike=%@ tag=%d",[[polygonView class] description], [polygonView tag]);

}


-(void)buttonPressed {
    NSLog(@"Button Pressed!");
    [polygonView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'you had no success'? What exactly didn't work? Did it crash? Or what?

Comment: Maybe this is the problem:  `UIView *polygonView = ...`  That's a local variable, not an instance variable.

Comment: (Might be time to examine those compiler warning messages.)

Comment: @HotLicks ...and read an OO conceptual paper. And a C tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get a hold of your `polygonView`:

```
-(void)buttonPressed {
    UIView *polygonView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject];
    [polygonView removeFromSubview];
}
```

Comment: thanks peter for this idea and this sounds logical to me! but the problem is it now trows a "Semantic Issue: Property 'window' not found on object type of type 'GameManager'". GameManager is the central class of my app where its all fired. i think the programatically created window its not recognized. maybe a bug or soemthings missing? -i'm using Xcode 4.2.1. and 10.7.5 many thanks for help

Comment: @HotLicks: reading and studying, yes -  doin nothing else at the moment:-) but some of these concepts can be quite confusing.

Comment: the problem is that i have no idea how to get that view to remove it after lots of attempts - polygonView is the name of the view an of a pointer to that (as far as i know).  but how to access the parameters of that view if you declare another method within your class.

Comment: Okay so if you don't have your `UIWindow` as an ivar then just access it like you did in your above `- (void)addNewView`. See updated code.

Comment: it crashes. debug consol text: 2012-10-29 12:17:10.789 OGLShooter[834:10a03] Button Pressed!
2012-10-29 12:17:10.790 OGLShooter[834:10a03] -[UIView removeFromSubview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfd1e500
2012-10-29 12:17:10.883 OGLShooter[834:10a03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView removeFromSubview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfd1e500'-First throw call stack:
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)

Comment: i even tried it with 
    UIWindow *polygonView = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] lastObject]; - but it still crases.maybe the opengl thing ...

Comment: when i change it to [polygonView setHidden:YES]; - then nothing is happening - i think it still does not "find" the window and the view.

Comment: thanks peter, but the app crashes again. i've tested that, too. and it says: instant method 'removefromSubview' not found(return type defaults to 'id') in the editor.

Comment: after lots of testing i found a solution. i had no chance to remove the view but i could change position or hide and show it. first is  that the implementation has to be within my main view. then i had to sort out the view by looking after the ojectindex of that view. to hide and show the view i have to hide the view first and add it vith addsubview. then i could hide and show it at will.